# How do I interact with sysfs or a driver that exports to sysfs in my own kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm trying to make a kernel module that exposes multiple devices to a single character device. I successfully written the gpio and cdev portion but I can't figure out the w1_therm device.

I use a raspberry pi with a DS18B20 temperature sensor and the w1-gpio-pullup driver with `dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=10` in the config.txt. It detects the temperature sensor and I can read the temperature via the `/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-062194159c7d/temperature` file. However I want to read it in my kernel module and I'm stuct on how do I interact with the w1 driver.

Do I have to rewrite the driver for the DS18B20 driver or can I somehow interact with the loaded driver? Or can I read the sysfs file from kernel space? Please can someone point me in the right direction or provide an example code?

Comment: The driver doesn't seem to export functions for kernel space use. There isn't much you can do except reverse engineer [the driver code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/df0cc57e/drivers/w1/slaves/w1_therm.c#L1525) and re-implement the functions in your driver. Another option would be to read the sysfs file from kernel space, but that's bad and you usually want to avoid it at all costs.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not for kernel space. I am not sure why you need that Frankenstein (your new character device driver) in the kernel to begin with.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thank you, I'll try to re-implement it.

Comment: @0andriy Unfortunately, I don't have a say in the matter, I'm just required to implement it.

Comment: A slightly off-the-wall idea is to implement the character device in userspace using CUSE. That's probably a really bad idea though.